# Combining multiple SQL SELECT statements into one

Tags: mysql, join

I need to combine the following three SELECT statements into a single SQL Statement:

```
1. SELECT TotalTime FROM Session WHERE device_uid = ${my_uid} ORDER BY StartTime DESC LIMIT 1;

2. SELECT HoursAtService FROM Service WHERE device_uid = ${my_uid} ORDER BY StartTime DESC LIMIT 1;

3. SELECT ServiceHours FROM Type WHERE type_uid = ${my_type_uid};
```

Preferably, I want to get my result as a single row with the following fields:

```
Result:
----------------------------------------------------------------
uid, TotalTime, HoursAtService, ServiceHours
```

I'm thinking that I probably need to do an inner join, but I'm not 100% sure how to approach it. Something like:

```
SELECT uid, TotalTime, HoursAtService, ServiceHours FROM Device AS t1 INNER JOIN (... -> continues
```

Doing a join between tables is easy enough, but how do you approach doing the join with multiple WHERE clauses for the various tables?

Could someone show me how I would structure the query?

**EDIT - Table Schemas**

```
Device:
---------------------
device_uid, type_uid, ....

Session:
---------------------
device_uid, session_uid, TotalTime, StartTime, EndTime, SessionTime

Service:
---------------------
device_uid, service_uid, StartTime, EndTime, HoursAtService

Type:
---------------------
type_uid, Name, ServiceHours
```

Comment: show your tables schema

Comment: what is the relationship between `Service`, `Session` & `Type` tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can merge above single queries in one query like below MYSQL Query:

```
SELECT Session.uid, Session.TotalTime, Service.HoursAtService, ServiceHours.ServiceHours
FROM Session 
JOIN Service ON Service.udi = Session.uid
JOIN ServiceHours ON ServiceHours.type_uid = Session.uid
WHERE Session.uid = ${my_uid}
ORDER BY Session.StartTime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Change the column names as you have in your related tables.

Comment: Hi there, I need to do a ORDER BY on both Session and Service tables though. Meaning, the StartTime in these tables will be different, but the ORDER BY must apply to both. Will this be covered?

Comment: Yes,  you can apply order by on multiple columns like Session.column_name DESC,  Service.column_name  ASC

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT ${my_uid} AS uid,
       (SELECT TotalTime FROM Session WHERE uid = ${my_uid} ORDER BY StartTime DESC LIMIT 1) AS TotalTime,
       (SELECT HoursAtService FROM Service WHERE udi = ${my_uid} ORDER BY StartTime DESC LIMIT 1) AS HoursAtService,
       (SELECT ServiceHours FROM Type WHERE type_uid = ${my_type_uid) AS ServiceHours
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What does the &{my_uid} syntax do? I have a uid variable that I reference as ${my_uid} (javascript), but I'm a bit unsure of the & syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to achieve the things which you mentioned, I have also taken care of square brackets for the keywords because service and session are SQL keywords.

```
SELECT 
    [Device].Type_uid AS DeviceTypeId, [Device].Device_uid AS DeviceId, [Session].TotalTime, [Service].HoursAtService, [Type].ServiceHours 
FROM 
    [Session] INNER JOIN [Device] ON [Session].Device_uid = [Device].Device_uid 
    [Service] INNER JOIN [Device] ON [Service].Device_uid = [Device].Device_uid
    [Type] INNER JOIN [Device] ON [Type].Type_uid = [Device].Type_uid
WHERE
    [Device].Type_uid = ${my_type_uid} AND [Device].Device_uid = ${my_uid}
```

Comment: This is not valid MySQL syntax

Comment: @Nick - So i have given the solution according to SQL Server but should work for MySql as well, could you help me to point out the problem in the above query?

Comment: MySQL uses backticks to escape words, not square brackets. Also it has different reserved words to SQL